# How to upgrade PHP to 5.3 and add in modules on CentOS 5.7 64-bit?

Tags: php, centos, yum

I've removed php5.1 using

```
yum remove php\*
```

I've installed php5.3 using

```
yum install php53
```

Now I need to make sure that certain supporting packages are installed. So I tried this:

```
yum install php-xml php-pear php-mhash php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pdo php-gd
```

But I get errors, like:

Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common

I found some [instructions here](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) but am not sure if I should trust them or not.

Thank you

Comment: You need to install the php53-* extensions. The php-* extensions you mention above, are for the php package you removed (and require php-common - if you look closely, it will probably be one of the dependencies). So try, php53-xml, etc. Some packages might not be included in the CentOS repository, I would recommend adding the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository if you need other extensions (as it is fully compatible with CentOS, and trusted). I'd advise against adding random repositories (such as the one from the article you linked).

Comment: @cyberx86, thank you. You and kswift are right about needing to use php53-*. Unfortunately, it did not work for 3 of the above. pear, mhash, and mcrypt. I will check with EPEL. Thank you!

Comment: @cyberx86 Hey so I went to EPEL and did not find anything when I searched "mcrypt" there. Should I just add the repository and try yum install php53-mcrypt and see if it works? How do I know if they have it?

Comment: Mcrypt is in EPEL - but I don't believe the other ones (mhash, pear) are. (See [here](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html) for all the 'letter p' packages (EL 5 x64) and [here](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/php53-mcrypt.html) for php53-mcrypt specifically)

Answer (score 1):

I think the packages you looking for are named something like php53-xml or php53-pear.

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely correct. I changed them all to php53 and most of them installed. But pear, mhash, and mcrypt did not. What do you think I should do?